# Ktor not reading settings from kubernetes config map

Tags: kubernetes, ktor, configmap

I am struggling with deployment of simple ktor application on kubernetes, namely with using config-map instead of application.yaml
Here is my kotlin ktor code

```
fun main(args: Array<String>): Unit = io.ktor.server.netty.EngineMain.main(args)

fun Application.module() {
    val secret = environment.config.propertyOrNull("custom.secret")?.getString()?:"nothing"
    val config = environment.config.propertyOrNull("custom.url")?.getString()?:"url null"

    routing {
        get("/env") { call.respondText { secret } }
        get("/config") { call.respondText { config } }
    }
}
```

and the application.yaml is:

```
custom:
  secret: "secretApplicationYaml"
  url: "urlApplicationYaml"
```

when i create k8s deployment :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: cm-volume
  name: cm-volume
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: cm-volume
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: cm-volume
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: from-file
          configMap:
            name: from-file
      containers:
      - image: bogmilos/volume-config-map:0.0.5
        name: volume-config-map
        volumeMounts:
          - name: from-file
            mountPath: config
```

with  respective config-map:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  application.yaml: |
    ktor:
      environment: "dev"
      deployment:
        port: 8080
      application:
        modules:
          - config.server.MainKt.module
    custom:
      secret: "secretCM"
      url: "urlCM"
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: from-file
```

my expectation is that the ktor would return on the endpoint `get("/env") { call.respondText { secret } }` the value of `secretCM`, however the value is the one from  `secretApplicationYaml`.
I assume that as the the ktor application is packed into the fatjar, that it reads only the application.yaml shipped together with it. When I go into the container and look at the /config directory, the application.yaml with correct information is stored. Could anybody help me?
I was trying to create container env variables, but in vain, the ktor reads only from the shipped application.yaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you say your `application.yaml` file in the `/config` directory has the expected contents, I assume that your `ConfigMap` configuration is correct. So it looks like your Ktor application is having trouble picking up the configuration file.

I assume that somewhere in your `Dockerfile` you have an entrypoint command similar to `java -jar myApp.jar`. Since you've used `EngineMain` in your code, you can provide the external configuration file using the `-config` key: `java -jar myApp.jar -config=/config/application.yaml`.

You may find more information about the command-line configuration of the Ktor app in the docs: https://ktor.io/docs/configuration-file.html#command-line

Comment: that has solved a problem!